# Scope/Filter collection from route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a standard resourceful route setup for 'Invoice' however I'm looking to add in the ability to filter the invoice records based on their state.

```
/invoices - shows all invoices
/invoices/unpaid - shows all unpaid invoices
/invoices/paid - shows all paid invoices.
/invoices/3 - shows invoice #3
```

I've gotten this working no problem with an explicitly defined match route.

```
match "/invoices/pending" => "invoices#index", :state => 'pending'
```

However, with a growing number of possible states this means modifying the routes regularly, and also means I'm repeating myself quite a lot.

My next attempt was to make this route a little more dynamic with named params in the match route.

```
match "/invoices/:state" => "invoices#index"
```

However this then negates the /invoices/id route and trying to look for /invoices/3 finds no records as it's searching based on the state parameter.

Can anyone help with defining a filter route such as this that'll work dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to take a slightly different route (excuse the pun) with this, by adding a constraint that rather then using REGEX used a method to look at possible states direct on the state machine.

```
# State based routes, which match the state machine dynamicly.
match "/invoices/:state" => "invoices#index", constraints: lambda { |r|
    # Get an array if potential state names.
    states = Invoice.state_machine.states.map &:name

    # See if the request state name matches or not.
    states.include?(r.params[:state].parameterize.underscore.to_sym)
}

# Resource routes go here.
```

This basically means that if I now go looking for /invoices/paid or /invoices/unpaid I get my expected index action, with the state variable set as expecetd.

However, doing something like /invoices/pay_soon which is not a valid event returns a 404.

Pretty happy with that solution, but thanks to the other suggestions which got me on to the track of using a constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Add regular expression as constraint in the routes:

```
match "/invoices/:id" => "invoices#show", :id => /\d+/
match "/invoices/:state" => "invoices#index"
```

It should select the only-number id-s for show, and the rest for the index.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, at first I thought this was working nicely, however I then noticed that this breaks my other resourceful routes such as 'new' and 'edit'

Comment: Routes evaluated in order of appearance, it should be okay if you specify it in the right order. E.g. the resource paths are first, then these two.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use routing [constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints) . Something like

```
match "/invoices/:id" => "invoices#show", constraint: { id: /\d+/ }
match "/invoices/:state" => "invoices#index", constraint: { state: /\w+/ }
```